# Stability in the small dt limit for RK45

Tags: stability-in-odes, runge-kutta-methods

I'm interested in the role of the time step for RK methods. I've attached a plot of the standard stability regime here where the x and y axis represent the real and imaginary parts of $$\Delta t \lambda$$ in the equation $$f' = \lambda f$$ and I pinched the RK45 relationship being plotted from somewhere else.

[image]

What's curious as this seems to suggest it is possible to move from a region of stability to instability by reducing the step size. In particular I'd like to know what happens when, for fixed values of the real and imaginary parts of $\lambda$, the step size is reduced.

In the plot I initially picked a point in x-y space (blue) which is inside the region of stability. I then assumed that the underlying parts of $\lambda$ were fixed and just reduced $\Delta t$ in effect scaling the first point by 0.9 in both axes, bringing to a point outside the stability region.

Is this calculation/interpretation correct?

Comment: $λ$ with positive real part are rather irrelevant for this stability consideration, as the exact solution grows as fast or faster than the error. On the negative side however, the exact solution falls to zero, while outside the stability region the numerical solution and thus the error grows exponentially.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I guess i'm curious why you discard the exponential solution? I understand the comment, but almost all 'stability plots' show the positive Re lambda region, so naively it seems to me it's worth considering? Additionally, even if the solution is exponential, does that boundary that the dots cross not still have some meaning?

e.g. backward Euler is stable in much of that region (although ofc it's only unstable region is also there)